# Core Plot - Hide graph beyond one side of axis

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, core-plot

I'm looking for a way to hide parts of a graph (namely the axes and plot) on a certain side of an axis (enclosed by the red boxes in the image below).  I would like the labels to still be visible and the graph to still be scrollable.

[image: graph]

I've tried setting `visibleRange` but it hides the axes for a fixed range, and doesn't quite work when the graph is scrollable.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Set padding on the plot area frame. See the Plot Gallery example app for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Just i have an idea, but i am not sure whether this will satisfy you or not.

I have used the `axisContstrains` property for both X and Y axis.

So the plots inside your boxes are not plotted for me. I hope this will help to this questions.